# Button onClick not changing dynamically in Solid JS

Tags: javascript, solid-js

I want to update the behaviour of a button onClick based on a boolean signal in solid js but it does not update when the signal changes. I tried using refs but no results.

```js
const [flag, setFlag] = createSignal(false)
  const trueFunc = () => console.log('true')
  const falseFunc = () => {
    console.log('false')
    setFlag(true)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={flag() ? trueFunc : falseFunc}>{buttonText()}</button>
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, the `onClick` attribute in your button uses the *initial* value of `flag`, hence the behavior you noticed. In order to change its behavior dynamically, try providing a function to it instead:

```js
const [flag, setFlag] = createSignal(false);

const trueFunc = () => console.log('true');
const falseFunc = () => {
  console.log('false');
  setFlag(true);
};

return (
  <>
    <button type="button" onClick={ () => flag() ? trueFunc() : falseFunc() }>
      { buttonText() }
    </button>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works but the problem is after initial toggle, condition get stuck in `true` hence calling only `trueFunc` when the button gets clicked.

Here is how you can do it in a clear manner:

```
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal, createEffect } from "solid-js";

function Counter() {
  const [flag, setFlag] = createSignal(false);

  const handleClick = () => setFlag(!flag());

  createEffect(() => {
    console.log(flag());
  });

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Flag: {String(flag())}</button>
    </>
  );
}

render(() => <Counter />, document.getElementById("app")!);
```

We toggle the flag directly inside the click handler:

```js
const handleClick = () => setFlag(!flag());
```

Another way to do it would be using a callback inside the setter function:

```js
const handleClick = () => setFlag(v => !v);
```

We used an effect to observe and print the flags value:

```js
createEffect(() => {
  console.log(flag());
});
```